# Caching web service connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.net MVC project that also uses web APIs. I'm trying to reuse a connection to a web service. Would something like this work? I'm afraid the connection will no longer be valid, but since its not null, I won't refresh it.

```
private ServiceClient GetClient()
{
  var cache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;

  ServiceClient client = (ServiceClient)cache["Connection"];

  if (client == null)
  {
    client = new ServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IPortalService");
    cache["Connection"] = client;
  }

  return client;
}
```

Comment: thought about using WEBAPI output cache ?

Comment: I haven't. I'll start reading up on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search for strathweb.cacheoutput.webapi2 in nuget
add directive

```
 using WebApi.OutputCache.V2;
```

decorate your controller method like so

```
 [CacheOutput(ClientTimeSpan = 30, ServerTimeSpan = 30)]
 public ......
```

and that's it your client page is cached